# Getting response of weather application latitude,longitude values from server

Tags: ios

I made the coding of getting weather application response.I could not get the exact latitude,longitude and population value.Instead of exact value i am getting response as a null.After that i cant get the other response.Also the response is-> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' "
Something i have done wrong in array index format.So anyone help me to get all values?

This is my coding

.M part

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

 {

 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSError *err;

 NSURLResponse *response;

 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 NSDictionary *dict1 =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

//NSDictionary *dict1a =[dict1 objectForKey:@"JSON"];

 NSDictionary *dict2 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"search_api"];

 NSArray *array1 =[dict2  objectForKey:@"result"];

 for(int i=0;i<[array1 count]; i++)
 {

    NSDictionary *dict3 =[array1 objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *array2 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"areaName"];

    NSDictionary  *dict4 =[array2 objectAtIndex:i];

    // NSArray *arr3 =[dict4 objectForKey:@"London"];

   //manage.transformName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[venueNem objectForKey:@"username"]];

      NSString *str1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict4 objectForKey:@"value"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str1);

      NSArray *array3 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"country"];


      NSDictionary *dict5 =[array3 objectAtIndex:i];


      NSString *str2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict5 objectForKey:@"value"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str2);

      NSString *str3 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict5 objectForKey:@"latitude"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str3);

      NSString *str4 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict5 objectForKey:@"longitude"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str4);

      NSString *str5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict5 objectForKey:@"population"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str5);

      NSArray *arr4 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"region"];

      NSDictionary *dict6 =[arr4 objectAtIndex:i];

      NSString *str6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict6 objectForKey:@"value"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str6);

      NSArray *arr5 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"weatherUrl"];

      NSDictionary *dict7 =[arr5 objectAtIndex:i];

      NSString *str7 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict7 objectForKey:@"value"]];

      NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str7);

  }

 for(int j=0;j<[array1 count];j++)
 {

    NSDictionary *dict8 =[array1 objectAtIndex:j];

    NSArray *arr6 =[dict8 objectForKey:@"areaname"];

    NSDictionary *dict9 =[arr6 objectAtIndex:j];

    NSString *str8 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict9 objectForKey:@"value"]];

    NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str8);

    NSArray *arr7 =[dict8 objectForKey:@"country"];

    NSDictionary *dict10 =[arr7 objectAtIndex:j];

    NSString *str9 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict10 objectForKey:@"value"]];

    NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str9);

    NSString *str10 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[dict10 objectForKey:@"latitude"]];

    NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str10);

    NSString *str11 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[dict10 objectForKey:@"longitude"]];

   NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str11);

   NSString *str12 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dict10 objectForKey:@"population"]];

   NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str12);

   NSArray  *arr8 =[dict8 objectForKey:@"region"];

   NSDictionary *dict11 =[arr8 objectAtIndex:j];


   NSString *str13 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict11 objectForKey:@"value"]];

   NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str13);

   NSArray *arr9 =[dict8 objectForKey:@"weatherurl"];

   NSDictionary *dict12 =[arr9 objectAtIndex:j];

   NSString *str14 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict12 objectForKey:@"value"]];

   NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str14);
}

 NSDictionary *dict13 =[array1 objectAtIndex:2];

 NSArray *arr10 =[dict13 objectForKey:@"areaname"];

 NSDictionary *dict14 =[arr10 objectAtIndex:2];

 NSString *str15 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict14 objectForKey:@"value"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str15);

 NSArray *arr11 =[dict13 objectForKey:@"country"];

 NSDictionary *dict15 =[arr11 objectAtIndex:2];

 NSString *str16 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict15 objectForKey:@"value"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str16);

 NSString *str17 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[dict15 objectForKey:@"latitude"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str17);

 NSString *str18 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[dict15 objectForKey:@"longitude"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str18);

 NSString *str19 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dict15 objectForKey:@"population"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str19);

 NSArray  *arr12 =[dict13 objectForKey:@"region"];

 NSDictionary *dict16 =[arr12 objectAtIndex:2];

 NSString *str20 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict16 objectForKey:@"value"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str20);

 NSArray *arr13 =[dict13 objectForKey:@"weatherurl"];

 NSDictionary *dict17 =[arr13 objectAtIndex:2];

 NSString *str21 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict17 objectForKey:@"value"]];

 NSLog(@"the response ==%@",str21); }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
 arra=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"search_api"]objectForKey:@"result"];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {


    NSLog(@"the areaName==%@",[[[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"areaName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"]);
    NSLog(@"the country==%@",[[[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"country"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"]);
    NSLog(@"the latitude==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"]);
    NSLog(@"the long==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"longitude"]);
    NSLog(@"the pop==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"population"]);

    NSLog(@"the region==%@",[[[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"region"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"]);
    NSLog(@"the url==%@",[[[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"weatherUrl"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"]);

  NSString *areaName=[[[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"areaName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"value"];
    [arra addObject:areaName];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at you first FOR loop. I am not saying the error is in only there.

**EDIT**

```
 for(int i=0;i<[array1 count]; i++)
 {
     NSDictionary *dict3 =[array1 objectAtIndex:i];
     NSArray *key = [dict3 allKeys];
     for (int j = 0; j < key.count ; j++) {
         if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"areaName"]) {
             NSArray *array2 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"areaName"];
             //Area name
             NSString *area = [[array2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"country"]){
             NSArray *array2 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"country"];
             //Country
             NSString *country = [[array2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"latitude"]){
             //Latitude
             NSString *latitude = [dict3 objectForKey:@"latitude"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"longitude"]){
             //longitude
             NSString *longitude = [dict3 objectForKey:@"longitude"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"population"]){
             //population
             NSString *population = [dict3 objectForKey:@"population"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"region"]){
             NSArray *array2 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"region"];
             //region
             NSString *region = [[array2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
         }
         else if ([[key objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"weatherUrl"]){
             NSArray *array2 =[dict3 objectForKey:@"weatherUrl"];
             //weatherUrl
             NSString *weatherUrl = [[array2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
         }        
     }
 }
```

Comment: { "search_api": { "result": [ { "areaName": [ {"value": "Chennai" } ],  "country": [ {"value": "India" } ], "latitude": "13.083", "longitude": "80.283", "population": "0",  "region": [ {"value": "Tamil Nadu" } ],  "weatherUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/Chennai-weather\/Tamil-Nadu\/IN.aspx" } ] } ] }}

Comment: Above this is my response.Please parse separate all the values.

Comment: See my edit, just use objectAtIndex:0 if you are sure that each array contains only one index. The response you posted has only one index so I used objectAtIndex:0. Best practice is to iterate that array.

Comment: Please see my above response.Also the latitude,longitude,population value in null brother.How can i get the values?

Comment: Latitude,longitude,Population value is null Now

Comment: Just use [dict5 objectForKey:@"latitude"] you don't need to use stringWithFormat. Lat long can be float? i am not sure, try some thing like this NSString *str = [[dict5 objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];

Comment: You are parsing wrong, Sorry I didn't notice it earlier. Wait.